# do-while or scanf() in c does not work

Tags: c, scanf, do-while

On running this code, the outer do-while does not work. It prints

> "Do you want to enter another number(y/n)-"

but it does not let me enter `y` or `n` in order to use the program again. Where did I go wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int num, x, sqsm, psqsm;
    char further;
    sqsm = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a natural number-");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        x = num * num;
        do
        {
            sqsm = sqsm + x;
            x = (sqrt(x) - 1) * (sqrt(x) - 1);
        } while(x > 0);

        printf("Sum of squares of first %d natural numbers=%d\n",num,sqsm);
        printf("Do you want to enter another number(y/n)-");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&further);
    } while(further == 'y');
}
```

Comment: your `printf("Enter a natural number-");` must be ***inside*** your outer 'do' in order for it to be executed more than once.

Comment: There are other ways to clear the \n character in stdin than fflush (which should only be used on output streams).  
You can getc or fgets or whatever.

Comment: @MikeNakis that does not help. I'm facing the same problem again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
scanf(" %c",&further);
       ^^^
```

otherwise white space characters will be read.

Also remove this statement

```
fflush(stdin);
```

because such a call results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you would see in the documentation of `fflush()` you would find this :

> For input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk files,
>   but not pipes or
>          terminals),  fflush()  discards  any  buffered  data  that has been fetched from the
>          underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application.

This actually means the `fflush()` is definitely defined well for input streams but with the given limitation of pipes and terminals.

In your example, the `stdin` is attached to a terminal stream (it is the default, you can even redirect/change it) and therefore using `fflush(stdin)` is actually undefined behaviour.

On the other hand, if you closely look into `scanf()`'s documentation, you will find this :

> ·      A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab,  newline, 
>   etc.;  see  isspace(3)).   This directive matches any amount of white space, including none,
>                 in the input.

What it actually says is `scanf("<a space character><your string>")` can directly be used to flush (or read and ignore, to be accurate) the newline characters (and others stated in the docs).

So, in your example, using `scanf(" %c", &further)`(with the space before `%c`) will actually produce the expected behaviour.